# PHP Regex Pegar a tag html

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de pedir uma ajuda para fazer um regex que separa os valores desta string:

```
<table>|<tr>[<td>#VALOR#</td>]</tr>|</table>
```

Eu precisaria que o regex quebrasse o valores da seguinte forma:

match 1: 
match 2: 
match 3: #VALOR#

Tentei, tentei e não estou conseguindo. Eu estava utilizando algo parecido com isso:

```
(<\s*?table\b[^>]*>).*(<\/table\b[^>]*>)
```

Desde já agradeço

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

```
  // String a ser tratada
  $string = "<table>|<tr>[<td>#VALOR#</td>]</tr>|</table>"; 

  // Expressão regular 
  $regex  = "#\<table\>\|\<tr\>\[\<td\>(.*)\<\/td\>\]\<\/tr\>\|\<\/table\>#"; 

  // Extrai o conteudo
  preg_match_all($regex,$string,$retorno,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

  // Valor #VALOR#
  $valor = $retorno[1][0];

  // Exibi o valor
  echo $valor;
```

Comment: Perdão amigo, não apareceu direito o que eu preciso. Seria assim:
match 1: `<table></table>`, match 2: `<tr></tr>`, match 3: `<td>#VALOR#</td>` .... Mil desculpas, e agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Não vou adentrar todas explicações sobre [não usar REGEX para HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118683/extrair-valor-existente-entre-duas-tags-com-express%C3%A3o-regular/118790#118790) de novo.

Creio que o que você deseja é isso :

```
~<table>.*?(<tr>.*?(<td>(.*?)</td>).*?</tr>).*?</table>~
```

#### Explicação

- `<table>` - literal deve se iniciar a sentença.
- `.*?` - qualquer coisa o menos possível ate encaixar o próxima sentença.
- `<tr>` - literal deve ter esta sentença.
- `.*?` - qualquer coisa o menos possível ate encaixar o próxima sentença.
- `<td>` - literal deve ter esta sentença.
- `.*?` - qualquer coisa o menos possível ate encaixar o próxima sentença. (seu valor estará aqui).

Com isso você criou 4 grupos :

- 0 - A própria *string* capturada.
- 1 - De `<tr>` ...`</tr>`.
- 2 - De `<td>` ...`</td>`.
- 3 - O valor do `<td>`.

#### Adendo

- Use o modificados `s` para o [dot capturar `\n`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/144070/14213)(quebra de linha).

#### Exemplo

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/qFEt92/1)

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como fazer o que você está querendo com apenas três matches exatos. Você não consegue capturar, por exemplo, apenas `WW` a partir da string `WAW` em apenas um capturing group, mesmo utilizando [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/5953895).

O que **dá** para fazer, no entando, é o seguinte:

```
$string = "<table>|<tr>[<td>#VALOR#</td>]</tr>|</table>";

$regex = "#(<table>)\|(<tr>)\[<td>([^<]*)<\/td>\](<\/tr>)\|(<\/table>)#";

preg_match($regex, $string, $retorno);

$match1 = $retorno[1] . $retorno[5];
$match2 = $retorno[2] . $retorno[4];
$match3 = $retorno[3];

echo $match1 . "\n";
echo $match2 . "\n";
echo $match3 . "\n";
```

No final, as variávels `$match1`, `$match2` e `$match3` vão possuir os valores `<table></table>`, `<tr></tr>` e `#VALOR#`, respectivamente, que é o que você quer.

E você pode ver a regex funcionando no [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/qX7hH9/2).

**Considerações:**

- A regex parte do pressuposto de que o único valor variável na sua string é "#VALOR#", o qual pode assumir qualquer string que **não** possua o caracter `<`;
- A regex não lida com espaços em branco. Se a string começasse com `< table>` todas as capturas iriam falhar.

Comment: Se você quiser que o exemplo lide com espaços em branco dá um toque, não pus porque achei que só iria tornar a regex mais complicada sem nenhum ganho real. E uma pergunta, se você sabe que a string tem exatamente esse padrão, e que seus primeiros 2 matches vão ser sempre "<table></table>" e "<tr></tr>", por que você não simplesmente constrói essas strings hardcoded e só captura o "#VALOR#" ?