# Extrair valor existente entre duas tags com expressão regular

Tags: java, string, xml, regex

Como verificar a partir de uma expressão regular se existe um determinado valor entre duas strings, por exemplo, as tags `<code>` e `</code>`?

Quero, por exemplo, saber se existe entre as duas tags o valor "03". Como escrever uma expressão que atenda tal necessidade?

Comment: Não conheço de java, mas procurar um parser de xml não é melhor do que regex? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Primeiramente

> HTML não é uma linguagem regular e portanto não pode ser processada por uma expressão regular.

Deve-se usar uma ferramenta apropriada para estes casos.

#### Contudo

Se você tem um intervalo "regular" na qual você tem certeza que sempre seguira o mesmo padrão, pode se usar REGEX.

```
String s = "<div style=\"border:1px solid #CCC\">03</div>";
String t = "div";
String p = "<("+t+").*>([^<]*?)</\\1>";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(p, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = r.matcher(s);
m.find();

System.out.print(m.group(2));
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/UPJ0WO)

[Mais sobre REGEX em java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)