# Como capturar tag textarea com new line?

Tags: regex

Como obter os valores de um `<textarea>` com Regex, incluindo new line?

Tenho a seguinte expressão para obter um `textarea`:

```
([<]textarea.*[<\/textarea][>])
```

[Exemplo online.](https://regex101.com/r/wC9oA3/2)

O problema é que se o `textarea` possuir quebra de linha, a expressão não consegue capturá-lo.

Daí a minha dúvida: **Como capturar o textarea com new line?**

Comment: Tratar HTML com regex é dificil e às vezes a ferramenta errada. Em que ambiente/linguagem estás a trabalhar?

Comment: @Sergio Estou utilizando C#, mas minha dúvida é apenas com a expressão mesmo. Eu não utilizo Regex para manipular o html, utilizo o [html agility pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Mas já conversamos sobre isso [no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31434017#31434017), apenas quis trazer a pergunta para o site também.

Comment: Randrade, por curiosidade, tinha algum bug na minha resposta?

Comment: @Sergio, te [respondi no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31478964#31478964), mas respondendo aqui também:
Desculpa, eu iria te dizer aqui no chat o motivo mais acabei esquecendo. Sua resposta está perfeita, não tem problema nenhum com ela. Eu mudei a aceitação apenas porque a resposta do GuilhermeLautert possui uma explicação mais didática, de parte por parte. Achei que isso seria de ajuda para que buscar. Mas estou esperando o tempo limite para poder oferecer uma recompensa.

Comment: Ok, tudo bem. A resposta dele é maior porque a regex é mais complexa :) Não sabia que querias separar tags e conteúdo. Bom conteúdo fica aqui na pergunta e respostas, nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O problema nessa REGEX é que por padrão o `.` não inclui o `\n`, desta forma teria de contornar essa falta, podendo ser com negação `[^...]`, que captura qualquer coisa que não esteja no grupo.

Para sua necessidade podes fazer assim: `<(textarea)([^>]*)>([^%]*?)</\1>`.

Veja funcionando em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/fH1eL8/1)

#### Explicação

- `<(textarea)` - captura literalmente `<` e gera um grupo literal com `textarea`, que vai ser usado como atalho.
- `([^>]*)>` - serão todos os atributos da tag, lembrando que atributos não tem `>` então usei a negação dele para pegar tudo, por fim deve terminar com o termino de tag `>`.
- `([^%]*?)` - aqui é conteúdo a ser capturado, eu usei a negação do `%` pois imagino que não var ter isso no meio, mas caso tenha é só trocar para outro caractere, por exemplo `¬`, lembrando que por se tratar de negação inclui todo e qualquer caractere que no esteja no grupo incluindo o `\n`.
- `</\1>` - por fim deve captura o termino da tag. que foi retomada com o atalho do grupo 1 `\1`.

#### Adendo

Você também pode usar a flag `s` para permitir que o `.`(Dot) captura `\n`.
alterando a REGEX para `<(textarea)([^>]*)>(.*?)</\1>`.

Lembrando que deve se aplicar a frag `s`.

#### Exemplo JS

```
string.match(/<(textarea)([^>]*)>(.*?)<\/\1>/gs); // aqui  foi necessário escapar o `/`, para não ser interpretado como fim da REGEX `<\/\1>`.
```

Veja funcionando em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/wC9oA3/9)

Comment: Podes colocar um exemplo da regex a funcionar aqui https://regex101.com/r/fH1eL8/1 ?

Comment: Não entendi o downvote, o Guilherme me enviou o link de teste e funcionou perfeitamente https://regex101.com/r/wC9oA3/8 (é que o Guilherme usou ~ ao invés de /)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert boa. Estava agora a ver, mas isso assim não apanha tudo desde `<textarea` até fechar a tag com `/textarea>` pois não?

Comment: @Sergio não sei se entendi bem, mas sim ele captura tudo ate o fechamento da tag, só que ainda separa em grupos, e o conteúdo fica separado dos atributos.

Comment: Cara merece +100 pela explicação do `s` isso é uma mão na roda, depois vou lançar uma recompensa pra ti :)

Answer (score 9):

Podes fazer assim:

```
(<textarea[\s\S]+?textarea>)
```

#### Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/oQ1qJ3/1

A parte importante é `[\s\S]+?`, que permite basicamente *tudo*, uma ou mais vezes, e o `?` diz para ser perguiçoso e concretizar o capture na primeira opurtunidade que encontrar.

Comment: Eu estava a tentar aqui: http://regexr.com/3du5c , o problema é que estava a incluir tudo desde a abertura do primeiro até ao fechar do ultimo. Que parte da tua expressão é que impede que isto aconteça?

Comment: @Miguel junta um `?` assim: http://regexr.com/3du5f

Comment: Ha boa... Obrigado pelo esclarecimento e pela alternativa

Comment: Esse `+?` é o que resolve o meu problema com o `[\s\S]`, agora acredito que será mais fácil portar os meus regex para diferentes interpretadores, como os do js, java, c#, preg. +1

Answer (score 5):

As demais respostas são as corretas e excelentes, eu só fiz algumas modificações:

- Modifiquei o exemplo do [@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/144075/3635) para:

  `/(<textarea[\s\S]+?<\/textarea>)/g`

  Teste: https://regex101.com/r/oQ1qJ3/2

  Isto para evitar coisas como `<textarea>abc<textarea>` (veja que falta a barra, mas no regex original do @Sergio estava a obter o match)
- Se precisar fazer um match separado dos atributos e do conteúdo, faça assim:

  `/(<textarea([^>]+)>([\s\S]+?|)<\/textarea>)/g`

---

- Modifiquei o exemplo do [@GuilhermeLautert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/144070/3635) para:

  `/<(textarea)([^>]+)>([^%]*?)<\/\1>/g`

  Teste: https://regex101.com/r/wC9oA3/8

  A resposta funciona perfeitamente, mas se precisar usar o `/` não vai trabalhar bem devido ao `</\1>`, claro que a situação varia em diferentes linguagens, isso é apenas pra uma situação especifica.

---

> **Nota:** Eu cheguei a criar um exemplo, mas meu conhecimento era mais limitado, todavia segue o regex:
>
> ```
> <textarea([^>]+)[>]([^<]+[^t]+[^e]+[^x]+[^t]+[^a]+[^r]+[^e]+[^a]+[^>]|.*)<\/textarea>
> ```
>
> Resultado: https://regex101.com/r/iW4xG3/1
>
> No entanto as demais respostas mostram caminhos melhores e mais simples, este é só uma alternativa para estudar

Comment: Estava a ver a tua alteração à minha regex e em casos de HTML inválido (que acho que é o que queres contornar) apanha duas textarea, é essa a ideia? https://regex101.com/r/oQ1qJ3/3

Comment: @Sergio sim é isto

Answer (score 4):

Olá amigo consegui fazer dessa forma:

```
<textarea\b[^>]*>((\n*|.)*)<\/textarea>
```

Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/oJ0iP6/2

#### Explicação:

- `<textarea\b[^>]*>` Captura a primeira tag, o limitrofe `\b` garante que a tag case com `<textarea`. o `[^>]*` casa todos os caracteres exceto `>` impedindo que a tag contenha dois `>>`
- `((\n*|.)*))` Captura o Grupo do conteúdo da tag. Captura qualquer quebra de linha `\n*` ou `|` captura todos os caracteres `.*`
- `<\/textarea>` Finaliza com a captura da tag de fechamento

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente em todos testes que fiz +1, apenas falta um explicação sobre a regex.