# Dando match em expressão regular com símbolos especiais de REGEX e quebras de linha

Tags: string, regex, match

Preciso de ajuda em uma expressão regular que dê *match* em uma `string` cujo:

- começo e o final de uma linha com o caractere `}`
- siga casando com tudo o que encontrar na linha seguinte (incluindo outros caracteres "escapados" como `\`)
- até um outro caractere `}` no final da linha posterior.

Tentei várias combinações e não consegui.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo de texto e esclarecer qual a linguagem de programação?

Comment: é preciso especificar onde será usada a regex, dependendo do lugar, os argumentos mudam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou supor que o *regex flavour* seja parecido ao de PHP, um dos mais comuns.

Também vou supor que os caracteres escapados são quebras de linhas, coisa que o operador "`.`" não captura, logo você pode usar essa *regex* aqui:

```
}(.|\n)*?}
```

Explicação:

- `}` determina que só vai começar a capturar, se houver fechamento de chaves.
- `(` declara o início do grupo de captura.
- `.|\n` faz com que capture qualquer caractere que não for quebra de linha, ou que seja quebra de linha (no final, qualquer caracter).
- `)` declara o fim do grupo de captura.
- `*?` quantificar *lazy*, garantindo que vai parar a captura na primeira ocorrencia da fecha de chaves }, evitando que capture coisas desnecessárias se houver mais de uma ocorrência de `{}` no código.
- `}` define a condição da fecha de chaves para acabar a captura

Você pode testá-la [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/b2bZjP/2)

Comment: Você pode fazer o `.` (Dot) capturar `\n` usando a flag `s`. conforme já expliquei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/144070/14213).

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementando, a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209787/112052) não leva em conta um detalhe importante da pergunta: os caracteres `}` devem estar no final da linha. Ou seja, se tivermos um texto assim:

```
abc } def
blablabla
xyz }
```

A regex não deve considerar o `}` da primeira linha, pois ele está não está no final da linha. Mas a solução proposta pela outra resposta [considera este caso também](https://regex101.com/r/hxrsEJ/1/).

---

Para que a regex considere apenas o `}` no final da linha, podemos usar o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`. Por *default* ele significa "final da string", mas muitas linguagens e *engines* possuem uma *flag* que faz com que ele também corresponda ao final da linha. No site regex101.com, por exemplo, basta ativar a *flag multiline* (opção `m` no canto superior direito), assim a regex ficaria `}$(.|\n)*?}$` [veja a diferença](https://regex101.com/r/wj2jGd/2).

Esta flag está presente na maioria das linguagens, geralmente com o nome de *multiline*: por exemplo, temos esta *flag* em [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), em [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), em [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE), em [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters), etc. Procure a documentação da linguagem/ferramenta que está usando, a maioria possui esta opção.

Outro detalhe é que o ponto, por *default* significa ["qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). Para que ele possa também considerar as quebras de linha, você pode usar a opção proposta na outra resposta (`.|\n`), mas esta opção ignora as quebras de linha do Windows (`\r\n`). Uma alternativa melhor seria habilitar a *flag* `DOTALL` (também chamada de *singleline*, que é um nome meio confuso, dado a sua função, que é fazer com que o ponto corresponda a quebras de linha).

No regex101.com ela é chamada de *singleline*, e se eu ativá-la, posso mudar a regex para `}$.*?}$`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/b2bZjP/8). Em [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) a opção é `s` (mas o seu nome é `PCRE_DOTALL`), idem em [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.S) e [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters), e em Java é somente [`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) (embora admita a sintaxe `(?s)` dentro da expressão, que também habilita esta *flag*).

Sim, em muitas linguagens as *flags* podem ser habilitadas na própria regex. Verifique a documentação, mas neste caso a sintaxe mais comum é `(?s)(?m)}$.*?}$` (o `(?s)` habilita o modo `DOTALL` e o `(?m)` habilita o modo `MULTILINE` - [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/b2bZjP/13) que o funcionamento é o mesmo).

Outra alternativa é usar `}$[\s\S]*?}$`. O [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s` considera espaços e quebras de linha, e `\S` é "tudo que nao for `\s`". Então `[\s\S]` é tudo que é `\s` e tudo que não é `\s` - ou seja, é um truque para pegar qualquer caractere, incluindo as quebras de linha. Desta forma, você não precisa da flag `DOTALL`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/owLEM5/3) (geralmente é usado em *engines* que não possuem esta opção).

---

#### Quantas linhas entre os `}`?

A regex acima pega quantas linhas forem necessárias, até encontrar o segundo `}` no final de uma linha. Mas pela descrição, entendi que na verdade você só quer que tenha uma linha entre os dois `}`. Neste caso, a regex poderia ser:

```
}(\r\n?|\n).*(\r\n?|\n).*}(\r\n?|\n|$)
```

Agora eu uso `(\r\n?|\n)` para considerar quebras de linha do Windows (`\r\n`), do MacOs (apenas o `\r`, já que o `\n?` indica que o `\n` é opcional), ou apenas um `\n`, que é a quebra de linha do Unix/Linux.

Um detalhe é que assim eu não preciso das *flags* `MULTILINE` e `DOTALL`. Então a regex agora pega um `}` seguido de quebra de linha, depois pega `.*` (zero ou mais caracteres) seguido de outra quebra de linha, seguido de `.*` (zero ou mais caracteres), seguido do `}`, seguido de outra quebra de linha.

Desta forma eu garanto que haverá apenas uma linha. Repare que neste caso, a *flag* `DOTALL` **deve** estar desligada, para evitar que o `.*` pegue mais de uma linha. E repare também que no final temos `|$`, pois além da quebra de linha, podemos ter o final da string (para os casos em que o `}` é o último caractere, e não tem nenhuma outra linha depois). [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/n3Jf9V/3) a regex funcionando.

---

Pode ser meio "tedioso" repetir várias vezes a mesma expressão das quebras de linha. Neste caso, existe o recurso de [sub-rotinas](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines) - que algumas *engines* suportam, consulte a documentação da sua linguagem/ferramenta para saber se é possível usá-lo:

```
}(\r\n?|\n).*(?1).*}((?1)|$)
```

No caso, os parênteses formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e podemos referenciá-los posteriormente com `(?1)` (basicamente isso quer dizer "use aqui a mesma expressão que foi usada no primeiro grupo de captura"). [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/n3Jf9V/2) a regex funcionando.

Algumas *engines* ainda suportam grupos com nome, que pode ajudar a tornar a regex um pouco mais "legível" (ou não, é uma questão de opinião):

```
}(?<linebreak>\r\n?|\n).*(?&linebreak).*}((?&linebreak)|$)
```

`(?<linebreak>` define o grupo chamado `linebreak` e `(?&linebreak)` significa "use aqui a mesma expressão do grupo `linebreak`". [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/b2bZjP/16) ela funcionando.

---

Por fim, algumas *engines* de regex suportam o atalho `\R`, que corresponde a uma quebra de linha (tanto o `\r\n` quanto o `\n` ou o `\r` sozinhos, entre outros caracteres - varia conforme a linguagem). Então você também poderia usar algo como `}\R.*\R.*}(\R|$)` ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/n3Jf9V/4)), ou ainda `}(\R).*(?1).*}((?1)|$)` ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/n3Jf9V/5)).